# Command Line program via Start.Process does not move cursor with its output

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line, terminal

I have two command line programs, `ParentProgram` and `ChildProgram`. I use the ParentProgram to start the child via `StartProcess("ChildProgram.exe")` and that works fine.

One of the key things I require is for this to be the very last line that runs for `ParentProgram`, because `ChildProgram` is a simple updater that has the primary job of downloading the latest copy of `ParentProgram` from GitHub. Thus, `ChildProgram` has a chunk of code that waits to ensure no `ParentProgram` processes are running before doing the update.

All of this works fine, but a strange issue is I am running into is any `Console.WriteLine(..)` calls I make inside of `ChildProgram` pipe out into the terminal as expected, **but they are failing to move the cursor**

So once `ChildProgram` has finished running the cursor still remains up at the last line that `ParentProgram` logged, and you weirdly have now a cursor in the terminal halfway down.

Is there a "proper" way to fix this issue, or do I simply have to do something hacky like modifying `Console.CursorTop`?

It's unreliable because I can't, for sure, tell where the cursor should end up, as the prefix for terminal input could be any length.

Is the easiest fix to just have `StartProcess` open another window entirely and have a "Hit enter to finish" CTA at the end of `ChildProcess`?

Comment: The use case is uncler, what cursor are we talking about? mouse cursor or the blinking pipe in the console window?

Comment: Terminal cursor in the console, not mouse cursor.